# SaveChanges() not saving data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I'm fairly new to MVC so please be patient.  Here's my action code in my controller in an MVC project I'm working on:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(User usr , string submitBtn, FormCollection form, int id)
{
    var db = new UsrSqlEntities();

    foreach (string fm in form)
    {
        if (fm.Contains("PayMonthOne"))
            usr.fName = Int32.Parse(form[fm]);

    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I've debugged this in VS2010 and each step passes through with no errors i.e. 'User' exists in my Entity Framework, my 'form' contains a value which passes to 'fName'.  However, running SQlProfiler in SSMS 2008 doesn't show any activity (and obviously not record in my database).  My entity framework is modeled on this db as, when I do an update to an entity, the changes in the db reflect in the EF.

I don't know why SaveChanges() isn't working.  Can somebody help?

Answer (score 4):

If you are updating the entity, you will need to connect the usr object to the db context and mark it as modified.

```
db.Attach(usr);
db.Context.Entry(usr).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

If it is new you will need to add it via:

```
db.Add(usr);
```

Then call your

```
db.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: Indeed. Once it goes to the client and comes back the DB reference disappears and needs to be looked up again.

Comment: There's no intellisense 'Context' option with my db - only ContextOptions.

Comment: try `db.Entry(usr).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: No, that's not showing either.  I have an 'AddToUsr' which intellisense tells me is depricated but it seems to work.  I'm using MVC 3 on VS2010.  This isn't my code and I don't know how to find out why I'm accessing depricated methods and not getting 'Context' and 'Entry' options.  Am I missing a reference? I'm using System.Web.MVC already.

Comment: `System.Data.Entity`, `{project}.Models`, `System.Linq`, `System.Collections.Generic` are likely suspects.  Replace {project} with your project name.

Comment: If you are just getting started, I would suggest you upgrade to MVC 4, and Entity Framework 5 before getting too far in.

Comment: Yes, I already have those included.  What is notable is that when the EF was created, the 'Pluralize' option wasn't checked.  Intellisense has 'AddToUsr' as well as an AddTo<entity> for every table.  Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following:

```
   var db=new UsrSqlEntities(); /* Module Level declaration */

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Create(User usr)
   {
       db.Users.Add(usr); /* Add usr object to Users DbSet */

       db.SaveChanges(); /* Save all changes to the database */
   }
```

This assumes that you are creating a new User, and Users is your DbSet for User objects, and your User object has a property "PayMonthOne" of type int or int?.

Comment: Would I be right in assuming 'Users' comes from checking the Pluralze' box when the EF was created?  If yes, then my EF wasn't created this way which could explain my earlier comment (AddTo<Entity> for every table?).

Comment: Yes, the pluralize box would change a table named "User" to a DbSet named "Users" that contains a collection of "User".  But I'm not sure where the AddTo comes from.  Are you using a DbContext?  What the base class of UsrSqlEntities?

Comment: The base class is ObjectContext.

Comment: Ah, that's an old version of Entity Frameworks.  Sorry, I really can't help you there.

Comment: You may want to consider upgrading to DbContext especially since you are just starting  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613116.aspx