# SaveChanges() in EntityFramework not saving changes. Showing "The function evaluation requires all threads to run"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Following is my action code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddCategory(Models.CategoryViewModel category)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Categories.Add(new Models.Category() { Name = category._Name });
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        var categories = _context.Categories.ToList();
        Models.CategoryViewModel categoryViewModel = new Models.CategoryViewModel()
        {
            _Category = categories.ToList(),
        };
        return View(categoryViewModel);
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I can successfully fetch the data but `SaveChanges` is not working. I see no exception thrown in the catch block and I am getting this error during debugging:
[image]

I clicked the thread icon before `_context.Categories.Sql` but it only shows a `SELECT` query.

Comment: If you don't have exception then your data should be saved - check DB. You get this message because you try to call this method from debugger.

Comment: Have you looked if the record is in your database?

Comment: @Dimitri yes I checked it. I found no records in the table.

Comment: @RomanDoskoch I checked the database and found no records.

Comment: Can you paste this "bool changed = _context.ChangeTracker.HasChanges();" between your add and save please and post the results here (thank you).

Comment: @Dimitri It is showing false.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva Strange ... Can you try "_context.Categories.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Added;" and see if that works? Also, do you have only 1 connection string defined in your web.config?

Comment: @Dimitri I can't find `Entry` extension method. In which namespace it is?

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva, in "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

Comment: You get the "All threads are required to run" message when you debug entity...entities. This is because the entity object is in reality a connection you have with the database, and the actions you perform on it get translated to SQL and sent directly to the database. This is why you can't debug through dbset<T> objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally with the help of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17055085/1124494 I was able to solve this issue. Although, I am still unable to understand the problem. I was using a common controller to get an `ApplicationDbContext` object. I was using a property like this in the base controller class:

```
protected ApplicationDbContext _context { get { return new ApplicationDbContext(); } }
```

I was inheriting this class in other controllers. I was correctly getting the data but not able to save it.

When I declared the `ApplicationDbContext` in child classes and used their own `_context` object to save the data, it worked.

If anyone can tell me why this happened then it would be a great help to future visitors of this question.

Comment: Everytime you access your `_context` field, a new instance of your `ApplicationDbContext` is created, thus every entity that was tracked by your context is no longer tracked. On a side note: I recommend you have a look at the dependency injection pattern and use constructor injection when creating new instances of your context.

Comment: @MarcoSiffert oh now I understand. Every `ApplicationDbContext` object has its own tracking. Thank you so much for the explanation. That's why in another project I was using `static ApplicationDbContext` object in base class and it was working there.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change protected to public of ApplicationDbcontext it can work,
please tell me if its right or wrong, thanks.

Comment: I will test it with this approach too and let you know.